# Connecting Oracle guest on VirtualBox to a macOS Host

Tags: sql, oracle, networking, localhost, virtualbox

I use oracle DB Developer on VirtualBox to create databases using SQLDeveloper. I use VirtualBox since I can't download SQL Developer on MacBook. I'm writing a Java code on eclipse with an SQL connection on the host machine. How can I connect establish a connection between the guest machine and the host machine?

I've tried to do the port forward option through VB's network adapter setting. When I tried localhost:8000, the page wasn't accessible. I'm honestly not sure if this is even a valid solution for my problem.

Anyone has a suggestion on how to connect my host machine to the database on the guest machine?

Comment: SQL Developer is available for OS X. Just click Download next to Mac OSX: https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html. You will also need Java 8 or Java 11 installed before attempting to launch SQL Developer from your MacBook.

Comment: If you want to avoid ClickOps try Vagrant together with VirtualBox. I use it all the time for testing purposes. There are plenty of vagrant boxes with Oracle Database tanked. Networking is easily configured with a line in your Vagrantfile:   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11". Another option is the use of Oracle Database in a docker container. SQL Developer is available for MacOS.